# Is it possible to move records(or rows) to unnest in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google bigquery,is it possible to move each record(row) to unnest?

For example,

```
Name    Physics Chemistry   Maths   Biology
John    94      85          86      65
James   97      86          84      54
David   90      82          76      45
```

I would like to move each record to unnest (like below example). How to move every row to unnest?

SELECT MAX(x) AS max
FROM UNNEST([94, 85, 86, 65, ]) AS x;

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model your problem as table with two columns - `Name` as `STRING` and `Grades` as array of integers:

```
WITH School AS (
SELECT 'John' Name, [94, 85, 86, 65] Grades UNION ALL
SELECT 'James', [97, 86, 84, 54] UNION ALL
SELECT 'David', [90, 82, 76, 45]
)
SELECT Name, (SELECT MAX(Grade) FROM UNNEST(Grades) Grade) BestGrade 
FROM School
```

Will produce:

```
Name    BestGrade
=================
John    94
James   97
David   90
```

**Update:** If we also want to show both subject with the best grade and the grade, we should model data slightly differenty. Assuming different students take different classes in school, instead of keeping rigid columns per subject, we can model grades as `ARRAY<STRUCT<Subject STRING, Grade INT64>>`, then the solution will look like:

```
WITH School AS (
SELECT 'John' Name, array<struct<Subject string, Grade int64>>[('Physics', 94), ('Chemistry', 85), ('Math', 86), ('Biology', 65)] Grades UNION ALL
SELECT 'James', array<struct<Subject string, Grade int64>>[('Math', 97), ('Orchestra', 86), ('Spanish', 84)] UNION ALL
SELECT 'David', array<struct<Subject string, Grade int64>>[('History', 90), ('Spanish', 82), ('Chemistry', 76), ('Physics', 45)]
)
SELECT 
  Name,
 (SELECT Grade FROM UNNEST(Grades) Grade
  ORDER BY Grade.Grade DESC LIMIT 1) BestGrade
FROM School
```

This will produce:

```
Name    BestGrade.Subject   BestGrade.Grade
===========================================
John    Physics             94
James   Math                97
David   History             90
```

Comment: Thanks very useful. Also it would be very useful if I get subject name. That is  94 is John's Physics mark, 97 is James' Physics mark and 90 is david's physics mark. any help

Comment: It is working. I would like to know why we need to use limit 1 in the query.   
SELECT 
  Name,
 (SELECT Grade FROM UNNEST(Grades) Grade
  ORDER BY Grade.Grade DESC LIMIT 1) BestGrade
FROM School

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Note: this solution is using original table schema as it is in question (*sometimes  it is hard to change/control what is given to you so you need to use it as it is* *:o)* ) and also it has no dependency on number and names of subjects/columns

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.scores` AS (
  SELECT 'John' Name, 94 Physics, 85 Chemistry, 86 Maths, 65 Biology UNION ALL
  SELECT 'James', 97, 86, 84, 54 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'David', 90, 82, 76, 45 
)
SELECT 
  Name,   
  BestGrade.*
FROM `project.dataset.scores` t, UNNEST(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)] Subject,
      SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) Grade
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), ',"')) kv
    ORDER BY Grade DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
) BestGrade
```

with results as

```sql
Row Name    Subject     Grade    
1   John    Physics     94   
2   James   Physics     97   
3   David   Physics     90
```